# Does Spring Boot allow loading external configuration from hidden folders?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc

So, I created an external configuration file named mystoreroom.yml in "/home/ivan/.config/spring-projects" directory, and I tried specifying its location when launching using the following command:

`ivan@IVAN-LAPTOP:~/Projects/Java/my-storeroom$ mvn spring-boot:run -D spring-boot.run.arguments=--spring.config.location=/home/ivan/.config/spring-projects/mystoreroom.yml`

After doing that I got an error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building my-storeroom 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.5.RELEASE:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ my-storeroom >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ my-storeroom ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ my-storeroom ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ my-storeroom ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/ivan/Projects/Java/my-storeroom/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ my-storeroom ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.5.RELEASE:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ my-storeroom <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.5.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ my-storeroom ---
[INFO] Attaching agents: []

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.5.RELEASE)

2020-11-04 00:20:55.577  INFO 31741 --- [           main] c.r.mystoreroom.MyStoreroomApplication   : Starting MyStoreroomApplication on IVAN-LAPTOP with PID 31741 (/home/ivan/Projects/Java/my-storeroom/target/classes started by ivan in /home/ivan/Projects/Java/my-storeroom)
2020-11-04 00:20:55.580  INFO 31741 --- [           main] c.r.mystoreroom.MyStoreroomApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-11-04 00:20:56.418  INFO 31741 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-11-04 00:20:56.427  INFO 31741 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-11-04 00:20:56.427  INFO 31741 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.39]
2020-11-04 00:20:56.478  INFO 31741 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-11-04 00:20:56.478  INFO 31741 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 847 ms
2020-11-04 00:20:56.525  WARN 31741 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'foo' in value "${foo}"
2020-11-04 00:20:56.528  INFO 31741 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-11-04 00:20:56.541  INFO 31741 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-11-04 00:20:56.551 ERROR 31741 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'foo' in value "${foo}"
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:405) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) [spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:405) [spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) [spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
        at com.repeta.mystoreroom.MyStoreroomApplication.main(MyStoreroomApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'foo' in value "${foo}"
        at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:178) ~[spring-core-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:124) ~[spring-core-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:239) ~[spring-core-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:210) ~[spring-core-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.lambda$processProperties$0(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:175) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:918) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1248) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        ... 18 common frames omitted

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.586 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-11-04T00:20:56+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 20M/212M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.5.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project my-storeroom: Application finished with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Then I moved mystoreroom.yml to "/home/ivan" directory and tried again:

`ivan@IVAN-LAPTOP:~/Projects/Java/my-storeroom$ mvn spring-boot:run -D spring-boot.run.arguments=--spring.config.location=/home/ivan/mystoreroom.yml`

This time everything was fine and /foo endpoint successfully printed "bar"

**Am I doing something wrong? Or is it suppose to work like that?**

Here's the code that I'm using:

**pom.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.repeta</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-storeroom</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>my-storeroom</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**mystoreroom.yml**

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          github:
            clientId: <hidden>
            clientSecret: <hidden>
foo: bar
```

**UserController.java**

```java
package com.repeta.mystoreroom;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class UserController {
    @Value("${foo}")
    private String foo;

    @GetMapping("/foo")
    public String foo(){
        return foo;
    }
}
```

Comment: On Unix, directory entries aren't "hidden" by an attribute the way they are on Windows; there's simply a convention that some UIs (including most CLI tools) omit entries starting with a `.`. Anything specifically opening the path (including Spring) will find it. I will note that your invocation (with the apparently nested options) looks strange, and there's a _possibility_ that it's being misparsed because of the presence of the `.`, but it's not an inherent restriction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I stumbled across the same problem. In Spring Boot 2.3.4 the "." in the path was not a problem yet. Since 2.3.5 is released, configurations under "hidden" folders are no longer found. In my case these are not external, rather configurations in the classpath as they are found unpackaged while building. In my mixed maven build environment I have "target" and ".target". The last one is causing problems since 2.3.5. Based on your description, I suspect that this is a new bug.

[Bug / Issue 23983](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/23983)

Comment: I'll probably agree with you on that. I recently opened my older pet project that is also using external configuration and I had no problem loading external configuration files in that hidden directory. Thanks for sharing your experience.